# MongoDB $sort usage

Tags: mongodb

This is my database/document.
Running:

```
db.Students.find().pretty()
```

Result is:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "scores" : [
        {
            "attempt" : 1,
            "score" : 5
        },
        {
            "attempt" : 2,
            "score" : 10
        },
        {
            "attempt" : 3,
            "score" : 7
        },
        {
            "attempt" : 4,
            "score" : 9
        }
    ]
}
```

How to display the scores in descending order using `$sort` ?

Comment: sort() in mongodb is used to sort between the documents. Here you mention one document and content as array which you wanted to sort. sort() won't work here.

Comment: Neil's answer in this answer section works fine for your requirement.

Comment: @svjn Don't bother it's only a round-about way of asking a homework question and the user has never accepted an answer. Bookmark them as someone never to respond to again.

Comment: @Neil, Seems so, you are right. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well you cannot do that using [**`.find()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) as any [**`.sort()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) modifier there is actually sorting the documents and not the contents of your array. But you can do that using [**`.aggregate()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/):

```js
db.Students.aggregate([

    // Unwind the array to de-normalize
    { "$unwind": "$scores" },

    // Sort the documents with the scores descending 
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1, "scores.score": -1 } },

    // Group back to an array
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "scores": { "$push": "$scores" }
    }}
])
```

So once all the elements are "de-normalized" into individual documents, the [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) pipeline stage takes care of re-arranging the order.